# Get SPL tokens minted by candy machine in order to sign the meta data Metaplex Solana

Tags: node.js, web3js, solana

I have set up metaplex candy machine for fair NFT mint in Solana. But My creator account was not verified. So I want to get all tokens minted through my candy machine and sign the metadata (creator list).

My QUestion is how can I get the SPL tokens minted by my machine and sign the metadata from my creator account.?

```
var filter : MemcmpFilter = {} as MemcmpFilter;
    filter.memcmp  =  {
        bytes: "MY_CANDY_MACHINE_ADDRESS",
        offset : 1
    };
     var config: GetProgramAccountsConfig = {} as GetProgramAccountsConfig;
     config.commitment = "confirmed";
    config.filters  = [filter]
    var data  = await connection.getProgramAccounts(toPublicKey("cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ"), "confirmed");
    console.log(data);
```

Help me to complete the code and sign the metadata

Comment: I too am interested in this question :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign the on-chain metadata for all SPL tokens minted from a candy machine, the Metaplex foundation Github has a CLI tool to do just this: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/6018393ecfcde06bc41c8ffc44c50913355c4ba6/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-cli.ts#L657-L683

Note: I've never used this command myself, but I've used other Metaplex tools before.